# List Comprehension python

Tags: python, список

Изучаю тему List Comprehension.
Удаляю дубли из списка циклом без set()

```
a = [1,1,3,3,5,5,0,8,7]
b=[]

for i in a:
  if not i in b:
    b.append(i)
print('b:',b)

b: [1, 3, 5, 0, 8, 7]
```

Теперь хочу переписать этот код, изпользуя List Comprehension. Схема вроде бы такая: [expression for member in iterable (if conditional)].

```
result = [i for i in a if not i in b]
print('result:',result)
```

> result: [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 0, 8, 7]

Но принтится изначальный список. Что я делаю не так?

Дописал вот так:

```
result = [b.append(i) for i in a if not i in b]
print('result:',result)
```

все равно получаю [None, None, None, None, None, None]

Comment: потому что b у вас не изменяется в процессе построения result

Comment: в этом не много смысла, но можно `[a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] not in a[i+1:]]`

Comment: Вы выбрали неудачную задачу для того, чтобы реализовать ее при помощи `list comprehension`. :)  Эта задача решается либо при помощи `set` либо обычным циклом. Если бы в Python был вариант метода `list.append()`, который возвращал бы измененный список, тогда эту задачу можно было бы попробовать решить с использованием `list comprehension`

Comment: Список из `None` получается из-за того, что `b.append(i)` всегда возвращает `None`. Извращаться, так по полной. :) `result = [b.append(i) or i for i in a if not i in b]`

Comment: Cпасибо, всех услышал, особенно про неудачную задачу))

Comment: Кстати, в случае `[b.append(i) for i in a if not i in b]` - собственно `b` и будет содержать требуемый список без дублей (как и в изначальном варианте). Ибо в этом случае запись через List Comprehension просто заменила цикл for в классическом представлении.

Comment: а почему вы против использования ```set```?

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1:** (Данный вариант работает лишь для данного вопроса, смотрите вариант ответа от @SergFSM, он универсален)

```
a = [1,1,3,3,5,5,0,8,7]
result = [i for j, i in enumerate(a) if a.count(j) <= 1]
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
from itertools import groupby
a = [1,1,3,3,5,5,0,8,7]
result = [i for i, j in groupby(sorted(a))]
```

**UPD. Вариант 3:**

```
a = [1,1,3,3,5,5,0,8,7]
result = [i for i in dict.fromkeys(a)]
```

Comment: Вариант 2 будет работать только в том случае если дубликаты идут подряд. Протестируйте это решение с `a = [1,1,3,3,5,5,0,8,7,1,3]` ;)

Comment: спасибо) поменял, так лучше

Comment: да, но теперь ваше решение возвращает результат не в исходном порядке. Такого же результата можно добиться гораздо проще и эффективнее: `result = list(set(a))` ;)

Comment: да. но выше написано, что без использования set

Comment: первый вариант тоже выдает не совсем то, что нужно, например для `a = [8,8,7,7,7]` он дает result = `[8, 8, 7, 7, 7]`

Comment: @SergFSM согласен. проверил, затем увидел, что вы уже написали верный вариант, переписывать не стал.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = [1,1,3,3,5,5,0,8,7]
>>> b = [x for x in Counter(a).keys()]
>>> b
[1, 3, 5, 0, 8, 7]
```

Или просто

```
>>> b = [*Counter(a).keys()]
```

Все вы делали правильно, просто результат не там где вы ждали. Изменяем список b и проверяем в нем же.

```
>>> a = [1,1,3,3,5,5,0,8,7]
>>> b = []
>>> [b.append(x) for x in a if x not in b]
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> b
[1, 3, 5, 0, 8, 7]
```

Результат выполнения List Comprehension нам не нужен. Мы эту фичу юзаем чтобы цикл был в одну строку) можно сделать так чтобы читающему это было ясно

```
>>> _ = [b.append(x) for x in a if x not in b]
```

Comment: Cпасибо огромное, теперь все ясно!

Answer (score 2):

вот такой еще list comprehension дает нужный результат:

```
a = [1,1,3,3,5,5,0,8,7,7,7]

result = [i for j, i in enumerate(a) if a.index(i) == j]
print(result)  # [1, 3, 5, 0, 8, 7]
```

здесь `a.index(i)` возвращает позицию первого найденного i и если он совпадает с индексом текущего элемента j, то включаем его в список